# Redireccion 301 .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Tengo varias URL's de un mismo directorio, pero cada una tiene una condición diferente para redireccionar permanentemente (301).

URL 1:

https://www.misitio.com/encuentra-naturaleza-en redireccionar a https://www.misitio.com/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en

URL 2:

https://www.misitio.com/encuentra-naturaleza-en/colombia redireccionar a https://www.misitio.com/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en/colombia

URL 3:

https://www.misitio.com/encuentra-naturaleza-en/bogota-colombia redireccionar a https://www.misitio.com/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en-bogota-colombia

> En este caso cambio `/` por `-`

Tengo estas reglas

REGLA 1:

```
Redirect 301 /encuentra-naturaleza-en  https://www.misitio.com/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en
```

REGLA 2:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/encuentra-naturaleza-en/(\D+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en/%1 [R=301,L]
```

REGLA 3:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/encuentra-naturaleza-en/(\D+-\D+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en-%1 [R=301,L]
```

El problema es que me está tomando la regla 1 para todas las URL, por lo tanto no cambia el `/` por el `-` en la URL 3.

Answer (score 0):

Con la directiva `Redirect`, todo lo que llega comenzando por `/encuentra-naturaleza-en` estaría redireccionando a la dirección de la regla 1. Prueba con la directiva `RedirectMatch` en la regla 1 usando algo como esto:

```
RedirectMatch "^/encuentra-naturaleza-en$" "https://www.xxx.com/naturaleza/encuentra-naturaleza-en"
```

Fíjate en el caracter `$`, que denota final de cadena.